# Equivalent in React of *ngFor in Angular 2

Tags: reactjs

I want to show a dynamic select, with values between 1 and 100 in a react component.

In Angular 2 is

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let i of numbers">{{i}}</option>
</select>

<!--numbers is an array [1,2,3,4,...100]-->
```

How is this in React?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `map` on numbers and create the options dynamically like this:

```
<select>
    {
       numbers.map(el => <option value={el} key={el}> {el} </option>)
    }
</select>
```

Check this example:

```js
var numbers = [...Array(100).keys()];

var App = () => {
   return(
      <select>
        {
           numbers.map(el => <option value={el} key={el}> {el} </option>)
        }
      </select>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the following solution.

Inside the render and return in Reactjs:

```
{
  myArrayOfData.map((val, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        { val }
      </div>
     );
  })
}
```

myArrayOfData can for example be `this.state.myArray`.

Answer (score 1):

`RepeatModule` is the equivalent in **Reactjs**

```
ReactDOM.render(<RepeatModule items={items} />,                 
    document.getElementById('react-content'));
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aravindfz/r4k43uf7/)**